# Sugar ORM cannot bulk delete

Tags: android, orm, sugarorm

I am using [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) in my app. It works ok except one action, that is, I cannot bulk delete.

My class is like this

```
public class Person extends SugarRecord<Person> {

String name;
String image;
String companyLFirst;
String companyLSecond;
String grade;
int ranking;

public Person(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

    public Person(Context context, String name, String image, String companyL1, String companyL2, String grade,
        int ranking) {
    super(context);
    setName(name);
    setCompanyL1(companyL1);
    setCompanyL2(companyL2);
    setImage(image);
    setGrade(grade);
    setRanking(ranking);
    }
//getters and setters below
}
```

I can save, I can listAll, but cannot deleteAll:

```
Person.deleteAll(Person.class);//does nothing, data is not getting deleted
```

Has anybody used deleteAll of Sugar ORM? Does it work actually?

Comment: I don't see a `.deleteAll` method in your `Person` class.  Is it in `SugarRecord`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey right, it is in SugarRecord http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html

Comment: @Roman i  can see your java file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used it in the example here. https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/example/src/com/example/SugarActivity.java

It certainly does work there. Is there an error logged in the background or something to determine the cause.

Comment: I switched to 1.3 jar, and still nothing. No logs, no deletions.

Comment: What was the problem in your project Roman? It would be helpful if you let everyone else know here too :).

Answer (score 0):

In case, if

```
Person.deleteAll(Person.class);
```

is not working. You can always delete the data in table with raw query.

```
Person.executeQuery("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = 'PERSON'");
```

Hope this helps